# capture url with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

from this URL [Amazon india site for all books](https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=book) and i want to capturn the page number urls given in bottom of this page

I have used beautiful soup and able to capture information in list.But i am not able to understand that how to create a complete URL to open up webpage using href information i captured. (basically how to re-write the url)

Here is code.

```
import requests
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = https://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=book

webpage = requests.get(url)
my_soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text, "lxml")
urls_at_bottom = my_soup.find_all(class_='pagnLink')
empty_list = list()
for b_url in urls_at_bottom:
    empty_list.append(b_url.find('a')['href'])
print(empty_list)
```

Here is the output:

```
['/book/s?ie=UTF8&page=2&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abook', '/book/s?ie=UTF8&page=3&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Abook']
```

How to use these captured link to open then ppage number 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add that root/domain to each element in your `empty_list`. you can either do it straight away then loop

```
links = [ 'https://www.amazon.in' + x for x in emptylist ] 

for link in links:
    next_webpage = requests.get(link)
```

or just concatenate as you loop through your populated `empty_list`:

```
for link in empty_list:
    next_webpage = requests.get('https://www.amazon.in' + link)
```